# Is there a way to start a container in detached mode from the Docker SDK for Go

Tags: docker, go

I'm writing a sort of Docker SDK and I'd like to know if there are some ways to trigger the dockerd endpoint /containers/{id}/start in detach mode. I found `detachKeys` but I didn't find clear the use.

Comment: I'd expect the relevant API calls to be detached by default; at an HTTP level, streaming "attached" content is a little tricky.  Do you have a [mcve] showing what you're trying to do?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have this repo https://github.com/fulviodenza/docker_rest which contains an implementation of the rest client with the start method (which is not working, idk why, i you can help me in finding a solution to that, we can figure out if they run in -d mode or not)

Answer (score 0):

It runs on detached mode by default, as far as I have experienced while trying out the Docker SDK.'

If you can post your exact issue, I might be able to help.

Comment: note: if you think a question needs more detail/clarity, you are discouraged from answering it until that detail/clarity is added. see [answer].